# Conditional mocking of a function based on the parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to mock part of the function based on the condition and for the rest want to use the actual implementation.

```
script_1.py

def retrieve_pod_size(pod_number):
  if pod_number == 3:
     return 'an object with size 3'
  elif pod_number == 5:
     return 'an object with size 5'
  else:
     return 'default object'
```

In my test I want to mock only when the application flow hits condition pod_number == 5 for others it should still execute the actual implementation.

In my test script I have

```
def test_pod(self):
  def get_mock_pod(pod_number):
      if pod_number == 5:
         return 'an object with size 6'

  with mock.patch('application.triggers.retrieve_pod_size', get_mock_pod)
```

Also, tried with side_effects but still have idea how to mix them based on the parameters/conditions.

Comment: can you share the assertions of the unit tests as well?

Comment: @catzilla actually Im testing another function which internally calls application.triggers.retrieve_pod_size.

Comment: I believe the mocking is correct, as long as the assertions are called inside the `with mock.patch()`

some things to check: (1) is the path of the patch correct? (2) is the mock applied? (3) it might be possible that you need to update the path of the patch based on the current module you're testing